# Express $I_{n}(x)=\int (x^{2}+1)^{(n-0.5)} dx$ with recursion

Tags: symbolic-computation

Let $I_{n}(x)=\int (x^{2}+1)^{(n-0.5)} dx$. I want to express $I_{n}(x)$ with earlier terms $\sum_{k\leq n} h_{k} I_{k}(x)$ where $h_{k}$ is a constant. I have no idea by which terms.

If I am going to do this manually, I am suspecting that I need to do here some trigonometric tricks to get this formula into some nice and easy form and then just simple integration by parts ([here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts)).

**Trial 1. Dead end.**
Perhaps, useful $$\int \frac{1}{1+x^{2}} dx = Artcan(x) +C$$.

**Trial 2. Dead end.**

Let $II_{n}(x)=\int cos^{n}(x) dx$ so by a few times integration by parts:

$$n II_{n}(x)-(n-1)II_{n-2}(x)=sin(x)cos^{n-1}(x)$$,

this may become useful -- no idea, look I find dead end here.

**Trial 3 and question. Some computational method?**

I would like to know whether some program can help with this kind of problems. I find it very erroneous to do many integration-by-parts again-and-again, some computer software to check calculations or help with this kind of repetitive problems that can be very time-consuming to realize?

Comment: This might fit better on math.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Substituting
$$x:=\sinh y\ ,\quad dx=\cosh y\ dy$$
you get
$$I_n(x)=\int\cosh^{2n}y\ dy\Bigr|_{y:={\rm arsinh} x}\ .$$
Now you have to set up a recursion for the integrals
$$J_n(y):=\int\cosh^{2n}y\ dy\ .$$
This can be done using partial integration: 
$$\eqalign{J_n(y)&=\int\cosh^{2n-1}y\ \cosh y\ dy\cr &= \cosh^{2n-1}y\ \sinh y -
(2n-1)\int \cosh^{2n-2}y\ \sinh^2 y\ dy \cr &= \cosh^{2n-1}y\ \sinh y -
(2n-1)\int \cosh^{2n-2}y\ (\cosh^2 y-1)\ dy\cr
&=\cosh^{2n-1}y\ \sinh y -(2n-1)\bigl(J_n(y)-J_{n-1}(y)\bigr)\ .\cr }$$ 
This gives
$$J_n(y)={1\over 2n}\bigl(\cosh^{2n-1}y\ \sinh y +(2n-1) J_{n-1}(y)\bigr)\ .$$
Finally the back-substitution: $\sinh y:=x$, $\ \cosh y:=\sqrt{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Is it possible to try difference choices for integration by parts with some software? Without having an idea for the choice of the terms, I find it very slow to try different combinations. How can I know that this equation for example has only one possible recursive form?

Comment: @hhh: See my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Plugging the integral into Mathematica gives

$$I_n(x) = x\ {}_2F_1\bigl(0.5, 0.5 - n; 1.5; -x^2\bigr)$$

The definition of the hypergeometric function ${}_2 F_1$ is well explained on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), including a set of recurrence relations. The one of interest to you, in Wikipedia's notation, is

$$F(b-) = \frac{2b - c + (a-b)z}{b - c} F + \frac{1 - z}{c - b}F(b+)$$

You get this by equating the second and fifth lines of Gauss's contiguous relations in the Wikipedia article. Plugging in your values, if I've done the algebra right, you get

$$I(n) = \frac{0.5 + 2n + nx^2}{1+n}I(n-1) + \frac{1 + x^2}{1 + n}I(n-2)$$

Hypergeometric functions are well studied and many numeric libraries include methods to calculate them reasonably efficiently.

Comment: Is there some easy way to replicate this process by hand or symbolically every step? I cannot see how the function can be expressed by such simple form. Now there is something missing, investigating.

Comment: I would try either converting your integral into one of the integral definitions of the hypergeometric function, or doing a series expansion within the integral and integrating it term by term.